# Can Multicasts sent via 127.0.0.1 in WinSock be read with INADDR_ANY?

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock, multicast

I have a simple multicast writer and reader pair that uses WinSock (code below). If I do not specify the IP address to multicast from (using IP_MULTICAST_IF), I can read the multicast using a socket bound to INADDR_ANY. If I use IP_MULTICAST_IF to send the multicast via 127.0.0.1, reading using INADDR_ANY does not work. It seems like binding the reading socker to 127.0.0.1 is the only way to see a multicast sent via 127.0.0.1. This is unexpected, as I thought INADDR_ANY also listened to the loopback address. Is there a way to have a multicast reader get all multicasts regardless of which IP address is used to send the multicast?

```
//CODE FOR MULTICAST WRITER
#include <sys/types.h>   /* for type definitions */
#include <winsock2.h>    /* for win socket API calls */
#include <ws2tcpip.h>    /* for win socket structs */
#include <stdio.h>       /* for printf() */
#include <stdlib.h>      /* for atoi() */
#include <string.h>      /* for strlen() */

const in_addr   MC_ADDR   = { 225, 1, 1, 1 };
const int       MC_PORT   = 1001;
const int       MAX_SEND  = 1024;
const in_addr   SEND_ADDR = { 127, 0, 0, 1 };

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int sock;                   /* socket descriptor */
    char send_str[MAX_SEND];    /* string to send */
    struct sockaddr_in mc_addr; /* socket address structure */
    int send_len;               /* length of string to send */
    WSADATA wsaData;            /* Windows socket DLL structure */

    /* Load Winsock 2.0 DLL */
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData) != 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup() failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* create a socket for sending to the multicast address */
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) 
    {
        perror("socket() failed");
        exit(1);
    }

#if 1 //IF THIS IS DEFINED THE MULTICAST READER UST BE LISTENING TO 127.0.0.1
    // Configure Multicast
    in_addr myAddress = { 127, 0, 0, 1 };
    if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_IF, (char*)&myAddress, sizeof(myAddress)) < 0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt(IP_MULTICAST_IF) failed");
        exit(1);
    }
#endif

    char iLoopOn = 1;
    if ((setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_MULTICAST_LOOP, &iLoopOn, sizeof(iLoopOn))) < 0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt(IP_MULTICAST_LOOP) failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* construct a multicast address structure */
    memset(&mc_addr, 0, sizeof(mc_addr));
    mc_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    mc_addr.sin_addr = MC_ADDR;
    mc_addr.sin_port = htons(MC_PORT);

    printf("Begin typing (return to send, ctrl-C to quit):\n");

    /* clear send buffer */
    memset(send_str, 0, sizeof(send_str));

    while (fgets(send_str, MAX_SEND, stdin)) 
    {
        send_len = strlen(send_str);

        /* send string to multicast address */
        if ((sendto(sock, send_str, send_len, 0,
            (struct sockaddr *) &mc_addr,
            sizeof(mc_addr))) != send_len) 
        {
            perror("sendto() sent incorrect number of bytes");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* clear send buffer */
        memset(send_str, 0, sizeof(send_str));
    }

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();  /* Cleanup Winsock */

    exit(0);
}
```

```
//CODE FOR MULTICAST READER
#include <sys/types.h>  /* for type definitions */
#include <winsock2.h>   /* for win socket API calls */
#include <ws2tcpip.h>   /* for win socket structs */
#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() */
#include <string.h>     /* for strlen() */

const int       MC_PORT = 1001;
const int       MAX_RECV = 1024;
const ULONG     MC_ADDR = inet_addr("225.1.1.1");
#if 0 //THIS_IS_REQUIRED_WHEN_MULTICASTING_TO_127001
const ULONG     MY_ADDR = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
#else
const ULONG     MY_ADDR = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sock;                     /* socket descriptor */
    int flag_on = 1;              /* socket option flag */
    struct sockaddr_in mc_addr;   /* socket address structure */
    char recv_str[MAX_RECV+1];    /* buffer to receive string */
    int recv_len;                 /* length of string received */
    struct ip_mreq mc_req;        /* multicast request structure */
    struct sockaddr_in from_addr; /* packet source */
    int from_len;                 /* source addr length */
    WSADATA wsaData;              /* Windows socket DLL structure */

    /* Load Winsock 2.0 DLL */
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData) != 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup() failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* create socket to join multicast group on */
    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        perror("socket() failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* set reuse port to on to allow multiple binds per host */
    if ((setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&flag_on, sizeof(flag_on))) < 0) 
    {
        perror("SO_REUSEADDR failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* construct a multicast address structure */
    memset(&mc_addr, 0, sizeof(mc_addr));
    mc_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    mc_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = MY_ADDR;
    mc_addr.sin_port = htons(MC_PORT);

    /* bind to multicast address to socket */
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &mc_addr, sizeof(mc_addr)) < 0) 
    {
        perror("bind() failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* construct an IGMP join request structure */
    mc_req.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = MC_ADDR;
    mc_req.imr_interface.s_addr = MY_ADDR;

    /* send an ADD MEMBERSHIP message via setsockopt */
    if ((setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*)&mc_req, sizeof(mc_req))) < 0) 
    {
        perror("B setsockopt() failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (;;) 
    { /* loop forever */

      /* clear the receive buffers & structs */
        memset(recv_str, 0, sizeof(recv_str));
        from_len = sizeof(from_addr);
        memset(&from_addr, 0, from_len);

        /* block waiting to receive a packet */
        if ((recv_len = recvfrom(sock, recv_str, MAX_RECV, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&from_addr, &from_len)) < 0) 
        {
            perror("recvfrom() failed");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* output received string */
        printf("Received %d bytes from %s: ", recv_len, inet_ntoa(from_addr.sin_addr));
        printf("%s", recv_str);
    }

    /* send a DROP MEMBERSHIP message via setsockopt */
    if ((setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP, (const char*)&mc_req, sizeof(mc_req))) < 0) 
    {
        perror("C setsockopt() failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();  /* Cleanup Winsock */

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: @rustyx Oh, sorry. I didn't inspect the code so closely, you're right. Could well be the reason you're mentioning. But Windows networking stack is a bit different anyways, and TBH I never tried this on a *ix system either.

Comment: I am using IP_MULTICAST_LOOP to enable multicasting to the loopback in the sender. I'm unsure if I need to do so elsewhere.

Comment: Why would you set IP_MULTICAST_IF to 127.0.0.1?  Solution: don't. Are you multicasting, or sending to the local host?

Comment: The reason is that I have an application that uses the multicast to stream data that can be picked up by third party applications. Sometimes that third party application resides on the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else interested in this, I did not find a way to get "ANY" to also get loopback multicasts. I eventually settled on just adding membership to the ANY adapter and the loopback address. Receiver code below. I did have some issues with memberships to 127.0.0.1 getting stick, but ignoring the error code seemed to allow everything to work.

```
#include <sys/types.h>  /* for type definitions */
#include <winsock2.h>   /* for win socket API calls */
#include <ws2tcpip.h>   /* for win socket structs */
#include <stdio.h>      /* for printf() and fprintf() */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* for atoi() */
#include <string.h>     /* for strlen() */

const int       MC_PORT = 1001;
const int       MAX_RECV = 2000000;
const char     *MC_ADDR = "225.1.1.1";
const char     *LB_ADDR = "127.0.0.1";

void PrintSocketError(const char *Prefix)
{
    int iLastError = WSAGetLastError();
    if (iLastError != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %d\n", Prefix, iLastError);
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int test;
    int recvsize_optval = MAX_RECV;
    int sock;                     /* socket descriptor */
    int flag_on = 1;              /* socket option flag */
    struct sockaddr_in mc_addr;   /* socket address structure */
    char *recv_str = new char[MAX_RECV+1];    /* buffer to receive string - make it 2MB so we can get packets from Cortex */
    int recv_len;                 /* length of string received */
    struct ip_mreq mc_req_any;    /* multicast request structure for "ANY" adapter */
    struct ip_mreq mc_req_lb;     /* multicast request structure for loopback adapter */
    struct sockaddr_in from_addr; /* packet source */
    int from_len;                 /* source addr length */
    WSADATA wsaData;              /* Windows socket DLL structure */

    /* Load Winsock 2.0 DLL */
    printf("Starting WinSock\n");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &wsaData) != 0) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "WSAStartup() failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* create socket to join multicast group on */
    printf("Creating Socket\n");
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        PrintSocketError("socket() failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* set reuse port to on to allow multiple binds per host */
    printf("Reusing Address\n");
    if ((setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char*)&flag_on, sizeof(flag_on))) < 0)
    {
        PrintSocketError("SO_REUSEADDR failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* construct a socket address structure */
    printf("Binding\n");
    memset(&mc_addr, 0, sizeof(mc_addr));
    mc_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    mc_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    mc_addr.sin_port = htons(MC_PORT);

    /* bind to multicast address to socket */
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &mc_addr, sizeof(mc_addr)) < 0) 
    {
        PrintSocketError("bind() failed");
        goto END;
    }

    /* ADD MEMBERSHIP to ANY adapter. This appears to not get messages
     * sent via 127.0.0.1, so we will add membership to 127.0.0.1 explictly below */
    printf("Adding membership to \"ANY\"\n");
    inet_pton(AF_INET, MC_ADDR, &mc_req_any.imr_multiaddr.s_addr);
    mc_req_any.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if ((setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*)&mc_req_any, sizeof(mc_req_any))) < 0)
    {
        PrintSocketError("IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP(ANY) failed");
        goto END;
    }

    /* send an ADD MEMBERSHIP message via setsockopt */
    /* buld multicast request structures for "ANY" adapater and loopback adapter */
    printf("Adding membership to \"loopback\"\n");
    inet_pton(AF_INET, MC_ADDR, &mc_req_lb.imr_multiaddr.s_addr);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, LB_ADDR, &mc_req_lb.imr_interface.s_addr);
    if ((setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, (char*)&mc_req_lb, sizeof(mc_req_lb))) < 0)
    {
        PrintSocketError("IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP(LB) failed");
        //I have seen this generally mean that the membership is alreayd subscribed.
        //For some reason ANY subscribed to 127.0.0.1 can take a little while to release.
        //Print the error and ignore it
    }

    // Large 1MB Buffer for receiving so we don't lose data.
    printf("Configuring RECV buffer size to %d\n", recvsize_optval);
    setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *)&recvsize_optval, sizeof(recvsize_optval));
    getsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, (char *)&recvsize_optval, NULL);
    if (recvsize_optval != 0x100000)
    {
        printf("ReceiveBuffer size = %d\n", recvsize_optval);
    }

    for (;;) 
    { /* loop forever */

      /* clear the receive buffers & structs */
        memset(recv_str, 0, sizeof(recv_str));
        from_len = sizeof(from_addr);
        memset(&from_addr, 0, from_len);

        /* block waiting to receive a packet */
        if ((recv_len = recvfrom(sock, recv_str, MAX_RECV, 0, (sockaddr*)&from_addr, &from_len)) < 0)
        {
            char buf[100];
            sprintf_s(buf, "recvfrom() failed: %d %d", recv_len, WSAGetLastError());
            PrintSocketError(buf);
            printf("\n");
            goto END;
        }

        /* output received string */
        char strFromAddr[128];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &from_addr.sin_addr, strFromAddr, sizeof(strFromAddr));
        printf("Received %d bytes from %s\n", recv_len, strFromAddr);
        //printf("%s", recv_str);

        if (recv_len == 1)
        {
            printf("exiting\n");
            break;
        }
    }

END:
    delete[] recv_str;
    printf("cleaning up Winsock\n");
    closesocket(sock);//also drops memberships
    WSACleanup();  /* Cleanup Winsock */

    printf("done!\n");

}
```